# Denied accsess to file [apache2, flask, python]

Tags: python, linux, flask, apache2

Raspberian, apache2, python3, flask,
I need to change network settings.

But when I try:

```
f = open('/etc/network/settings.txt', 'w') \
f.write('1234')
```

It gives me an error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/network/settings.txt'
```

I really dont understand what is going on.

I try to change apache2 settings :

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Add to `apache2.conf` and to `/sites-avialable/webapp.conf` , but it is doesn't work

Comment: Perhaps you don't have write access to this file

Comment: what i need to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Created file named settings.txt

   chmod 777 settings.txt
2. add to apache2/sites-enabled/webApp.conf:

   <Directory /etc/network/>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
   </Directory>

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have write-access to /etc/network/settings.txt.
You need to either run the script as root/sudo or give your account permission to write the file with chown and chmod.

Tutorials with examples on how to change ownership and permissions on files:
https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-chown-command/
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-chmod-command/